# Are We responsible for reloading new AdMob Banner Ads?

Tags: android, admob

[Edit at bottom.]

When we want a new Interstitial AdMob add during a break in the normal flow of the App, we are responsible for triggering a new ad to be loaded. I do this by:

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build());
```

I do this every time I want a new Interstitial add to be triggered. ***I think that is right?***

However, I also have a Banner ad at the bottom of one of my activities. At the start I get a new ad with:

```
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Now this is the bit I am unsure about.

If I feel it has been a bit of a while since that last Banner ad has been called do ***I*** call that `adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` bit of code again?

**Am I responsible for doing this?** Or does AdMob have something in the background they run that updates those banner ads?

Edit:

On this page it says do not refresh banner ads in less than 60 seconds. I am doing it every 5 minutes, and only after a user trigger event. But within that statement is the implication that I am responsible for the refresh of a banner ad. Here is the page here:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

What does everyone else think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Do `loadAd()` again.
2. You can recreate banner and call request again.
3. Change refresh time at your admin panel.
4. Try to use more useful types of ads. Such as fullscreen, video, native ads, etc.